# How can I implement "operator=" and "copy c'tor" correctly in this case?

Tags: class, c++11, operator-overloading, copy-constructor, derived-class

Given the classes `BaseClass` and `SomeClass` (that implements `operator=` and `copy c'tor`) , I writed the following class:

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
 SomeClass* a1;
 SomeClass* a2;
public:
 // constructors go here …
 ~DerivedClass() { delete a1; delete a2;}
 // other functions go here ...
};
```

**And my question is:** How can I implements `operator=` of the class `DerivedClass`? And how can I implements `copy c'tor` of this class?

I thought to implements the `operator=` in the following way:

```
DerivedClass& operator=(const DerivedClass& d)  {
if (this==&d) return *this;
SomeClass* tmp1 = new SomeClass (*(d.a1));
SomeClass* tmp2 = NULL;
try {
tmp2 = new SomeClass(*(d.a2));
} catch (const std::exception& e) {
delete tmp1;
throw e;
}
delete this->a1;
delete this->a2;
this->a1 = tmp1;
this->a2 = tmp2;
return *this;
}
```

But I'm not sure about the solution, in particular, what about the fields of `BaseClass`?

In addition, how can I implement the `copy c'tor` of `DerivedClass`? Can I do it with `operator=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is that you *don't* implement them, and instead go for [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero). That can be easily accomplished with e.g. [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (if shared ownership of `a1` and `a2` is acceptable).

But if you must implement your own copy-constructor and copy-assignment operators, then you first of all need to invoke the parent class constructor or operator, before you do your own copying.

For the constructor, you use the constructor-initializer list:

```
DerivedClass(DerivedClass const& other)
    : BaseClass(other), a1(new SomeClass(*other.a1)), a2(new SomeClass(*other.a2))
{}
```

The part `a1(new SomeClass(*other.a1)` creates a new `SomeClass` object using its copy-constructor, and initializes your member `a1` to point to the new object.

And this last part should be a hint for you copy-assignment operator as well, as it can be used there too:

```
DerivedClass& operator=(DerivedClass const& other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        // First let the parent copy itself
        BaseClass::operator=(other);

        // Deep copy of the members
        delete a1;
        a1 = new SomeClass(*other.a1);

        delete a2;
        a2 = new SomeClass(*other.a2);
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: But it's not keep about the values of `this` in case of exception, no? Namely, if while we will do `a2 = new SomeClass(*(other.a2));` we will get `std::bad_alloc` , so we will want to keep about the fields of `this` like in the beginning , no?

Comment: In addition, exists way to implement the `copy constructor` by `operator=` ?

Comment: @Software_t Almost all exceptions are really non-recoverable. If you don't have enough memory to allocate the object, then what is the point of continuing at all? Okay, there are cases where you can free up memory, but then object creation has to be redone, and so has the assignment, and you have to do that on a higher level than your copy constructor and assignment operators.

Comment: Ok, and only for the understanding, if I want, can I to do it `BaseClass::operator=(other);` after the updating of `a1` and `a2`? Or that it's must be in the beginning?

Comment: @Software_t It can be in any order.

Comment: Ok, and what about the `copy c'tor` , exists a way to implement it with `operator=`? (It's clear to me how to implement it like in your way, but I want to know if I can to do it with `oeprator=` and if yes, how can I do it.)

Comment: For example, can I implement the `copy c'tor` like that?   `*this = d;`  while `d` is the input ?

Comment: @Software_t Only if you properly initialize the local members first (e.g. put `a1(nullptr)` in the initializer list) which makes no sense if you can do it all in the initializer list to begin with. And the initializer-list "call" to the base class copy-constructor needs to be done anyway, which means you copy the base twice.